# Eucledian distance to point source

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am stimulating a model via a point source, which is located above (z-direction)-- to be able to compute the impact of the stimulation i need to compute the eucledian distance from this point power source to each mid of compartment (see picute).

I tried it this way, but the results are strange -- maybe the computation of the distance is wrong...

```
x_Mid = np.zeros(nComp)
y_Mid = np.zeros(nComp)
z_Mid = np.zeros(nComp)
for i in range(0, nComp):
    y_Mid[i] = 0.
    if i == 0:
        x_Mid[i] = (lComp[i] / 2.)
        z_Mid[i] = 1*elecShift
        compDist[i] = distance.euclidean(x_Mid,y_Mid,z_Mid)*10**(-4)

    else:
        x_Mid[i] = x_Mid[i - 1] + (lComp[i - 1] / 2.) + (lComp[i] / 2.)
        z_Mid[i] = 1*elecShift
        compDist[i] = distance.euclidean(x_Mid,y_Mid,z_Mid)*10**(-4)
```

`lcomp` is the length of the compartment. y - direction is zero, because its a 2D Model. `elecshift` is the distance of the point source in z-direction and the units are micrometer (therefore then its multiplied by 10^-4 to give it in centimeter). `nComp` is the number of compartments.

Is the computation of the eucledean distance from the source to each compartment center correct?

[image: pic1]

Comment: What is `distance.euclidean()`?

Comment: What does it mean that 'results are strange'? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @rpoleski when i increase the diameter of the comaprtments the impact of the source should be smaller, but it gets larger

Comment: @rpoleski distance.euclidean() is implemented in numpy and calcualtes the euclidean distance for points

Comment: Strange. I'm trying to find `numpy.distance.euclidean()` and cannot find it online or in my numpy

Comment: What is a difference between compartment length and diameter? How do you asses 'the impact of the source'? Please provide MRE. Currently, I don't even understand the question.

Comment: @rpoleski the rest of the code is a math problem, which consists of a system of ODEs. One compartment is assumed to be of cylincdrical shape -- therefore it needs a radius and a length. I just wanted to know if the euclidean distance to the compartment centers from the source is correctly calculated

Comment: I assume that distance.euclidean() is this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html

Comment: @Vorsprung yes this is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the source is at `[0, 0, 0]`.

You can calculate three vectors in a simpler way:

```py
x_Mid = np.cumsum(lComp) - lComp / 2.
y_Mid = np.zeros_like(x_Mid)
z_Mid = elecShift * np.ones_like(x_Mid)
```

Then the simplest calculation of distance is just:

```py
compDist = np.sqrt(x_Mid**2 + y_Mid**2 + z_Mid**2) * 1.e-4
```

or even:

```py
compDist = np.sqrt(x_Mid**2 + elecShift**2) * 1.e-4
```

And if you want to use [function from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html), then according to API, use:

```py
for i in range(0, nComp):
  compDist[i] = distance.euclidean([x_Mid[i], y_Mid[i], z_Mid[i]], 0.)*10**(-4)
```

Your code was providing current `x_Mid` as one point, `y_Mid` as second one and `z_Mid` as weights to `distance.euclidean()`.

Comment: ! thank you! so its flexibel to move the electrode in the z-direction. the source can be also placed above the second compartment etc. many thanks

Comment: dear @rpoleski: but what if i want to place the electrode above another compartment? then there should be a negative sign in the opposite direction: lets assume i place it over the first compartment -- then for example i have x_mid = [0,100,200,300,400,500...] , but when i place it over the third compartment it should be x_mid = [-200,-100,0,100,200,...] , can i incorporate this somehow ?

Comment: If you know x_mid then just use formulat for `compDist` once more (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: i am not really used to python (but i need to do it in this language), for example when compartment is of length LEN, then i would simply write in matlab x_Mid =  -(location-1)*LEN:LEN:(nComp-location)*LEN , where for example location = 1 or 3 or whatever, then i get the correct vector of x_mid

Comment: the question is the following: i want to place the electrode at a certain x-location (because the z-direction is always elecshift), the y-direction = 0. Now when i place the electrode above the first compartment, then the calculation you wrote is correct, but when it is placed above the third compartment for example, then the x-values of first and second compartment need to be of different sign, since the electrode position is more or less the "center" then.

Comment: Then just subtract the x-location of the compartment below the electrode from all x values.

Comment: i dont get it -- lets assume i choose location = 3, then it would be np.cumsum(lComp) - lComp / 2. - (np.cumsum(lCOmp(until location = 3)) - lcomp/2 (until location = 3)

Comment: `x_Mid = np.cumsum(lComp) - lComp / 2.` and `x_Mid -= x_Mid[3]`.